# Get Assembly of program from a DLL

Tags: c#, .net, dll, .net-assembly, methodinfo

I would like to access a function of a program from which is attached a DLL.

In DLL I've tried:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
Type type = assembly.GetType("Uranium");
MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod("Util");

methodInfo.Invoke("SendClient", new object[] { Packet.GetData()});
```

But not works I get a null exception but not say the line.
The running program is called and namespace is 'Uranium', the class is 'Util' and function is 'SendClient'.

Comment: do you get any exception?

Comment: Since you probably want to use a DLL that is attached, you need to use GetAssembly(), not GetExecutingAssembly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been able solve it on my own.

Code:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("Uranium.exe");
Type type = assembly.GetType("Uranium.Util");
MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod("SendClient");

methodInfo.Invoke(null, new object[] { Packet.GetData() });
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to find the assembly that contains the type. Also, you need to pass the class name to `GetType()`, not the namespace, and method name to `GetMethod()`, not class name.

```
foreach (Assembly currentassembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()) 
{
    Type t = currentassembly.GetType("Util", false, true);
    if (t != null) 
    {
        MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod("SendClient");
        methodInfo.Invoke(Activator.CreateInstance(t),new object[] { Packet.GetData()});
    }
}
```

Comment: He has already stated the the class is located in the executing Assemply. No need to loop.

Comment: No Assembly contains the 'Util' class. But it does contain.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can read from the code you've posted you try to invoke the function Util of class Uranium. And you're passing a string as the instance of the class.

This should be more like what you're trying to do:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
Type type = assembly.GetType("Util");
MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod("SendClient");

methodInfo.Invoke(Activator.CreateInstance(type), new object[] { Packet.GetData()});
```

If `SendClient` is a static member function then `Activator.CreateInstance(type)` can be replaced with `null`.
And of course you should add checks that the `GetType` and `GetMethod` return values are not `null`

Comment: Is the class public? If it's private class you might not see it at all.

Comment: Yes, is public. namespace Uranium{ public class Util{}}